# Python create a list of lists groupped from unique values

Tags: python, list

In my code i have a list like this:

```
l1 = [['var1', '2'], ['var1', '5'], ['var1', 'a'], ['var2', '90']]
```

i try to generate a code that create starting from l1 a list like that:

```
[[['var1','2'],['var2','90']],[['var1','5'],['var2','90']],[['var1','a'], ['var2','90']]]
```

in practice three different list based on unique value but i have no idea how to perform this task,
Is there a particular python func for achieve this result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you need to start by grouping against your first elements

```
from itertools import groupby, product
from operator import itemgetter

grps = [list(grp) for _, grp in groupby(l1, key=itemgetter(0))]
# itemgetter(0) is the default, but this is somewhat more explicit.
```

then use `itertools.product` over those groups

```
result = product(*grps)
```

this will give you:

```
>>> l1 = [['var1', '2'], ['var1', '5'], ['var1', 'a'], ['var2', '90']]
result = [(['var1', '2'], ['var2', '90']), (['var1', '5'], ['var2', '90']), (['var1', 'a'], ['var2', '90'])]
>>> l2 = [['var1', '7'], ['var2', '2'], ['var2', '5']]
result = [(['var1', '7'], ['var2', '2']), (['var1', '7'], ['var2', '5'])]
```

Your final function then becomes:

```
from itertools import groupby, product
from operator import itemgetter

def product_by_grouping(lst):
    grps = [list(grp) for _, grp in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))]
    return product(*grps)
```

Comment: bonus points to anyone who can figure out why you need to cast `grp` to a list. It feels like `product` should be handling that internally but it doesn't seem to in this case (but does for more trivial examples!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpacking in Python3:

```
l1 = [['var1', '2'], ['var1', '5'], ['var1', 'a'], ['var2', '90']]
*l, _val = l1
l2 = [[i, _val] for i in l]
```

Output:

```
[[['var1', '2'], ['var2', '90']], [['var1', '5'], ['var2', '90']], [['var1', 'a'], ['var2', '90']]]
```

Comment: Not sure why you got the downvote -- this is exactly the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thank you. This solution is the cleanest way I can think of to solve this problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer but if i have for example l1=[['var1','7'],['var2','2'],['var2','5']] the result is [[['var1', '7'], ['var2', '5']], [['var2', '2'], ['var2', '5']]] and not [[['var1', '7'], ['var2', '2']], [['var1', '7'], ['var2', '5']]] like i would

Comment: @ManuelSanti I am not sure I understand the logic as to how that list is created. Can you explain?

Comment: thanks @Ajax1234, i would a list where not unique var/val are spltted in different list like in previous example. var2 is a not unique value in original list hence in new list have to be associated to var1  for every list in list